# UIImagePicker is not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement a button over the default camera view that opens the photo library once taped. Right now I implemented a custom overlay view class that displays the button, however the UIImagePicker is not presented or is invisible (covered by multiple views).

CameraOverlayView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CameraOverlayView : UIView <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{}
- (UIViewController *)viewController;
- (void) button1:(UIButton *)paramSender;
@end
```

CameraOverlayView.m

```
#import "CameraOverlayView.h"


@implementation CameraOverlayView


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        //clear the background color of the overlay
        self.opaque = NO;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        //add a simple button to the overview
        //with no functionality at the moment
        UIButton *button = [UIButton
                            buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(button1:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTitle:@"Select" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        CGPoint buttonOffset = CGPointMake( ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - button.frame.size.width) / 2, ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - button.frame.size.height) / 2);

        button.frame = CGRectMake(buttonOffset.x, buttonOffset.y, 400, 50);
        [self addSubview:button];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) button1:(UIButton *)paramSender{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self.viewController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    //debugging
    NSLog(@"sup!");
}

//find the first responder to access the UIViewController
- (UIViewController *)viewController {
    if ([self.nextResponder isKindOfClass:UIViewController.class])
        return (UIViewController *)self.nextResponder;
    else
        return nil;
}
```

Note that when I run the code there are no errors and the "Select" button shows correctly. And when I tap the button it displays the NSLog message but no photo library opens. Does anyone know what's the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to make sure you gave it permission , if you say ever say no, it will not show up or give you erros

Comment: @meda, i never set the permission, is the default value NO?

Comment: the reference to self.viewcontroller is set?

Comment: [Download sample](https://mega.co.nz/#!2JgijIZT!mvDDeJIdUHRNWgmzn0k2A1GMcx0YCNtlUMk1KaJv_kA) @forseqn you can check this sample I worked on a while ago, you should be able to tweak it